# Is it possible to print columnized output with os.listdir()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, listdir

I'm looking to create two columns with os.listdir. Code is standard listdir().

```
for f in os.listdir(os.curdir):
                print f
```

Output looks like as follows:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

But I'm trying to achieve:

```
file1    file3
file2    file4
```

Is that (easily) achievable with os.listdir()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir` just returns a list, doesn't print it nicely like `ls -C2` would do (note that you don't need python for that if you have `ls` in your system)

You could do it this way for 2 colums:

```
import os,itertools

dl=os.listdir(".")

for t in itertools.zip_longest(dl[::2],dl[1::2],fillvalue=""):
    print("{:<20} {:<20}".format(*t))
```

that would interleave the values together (with `zip_longest` to avoid forgetting an odd one) and format using 20 spaces for each value.

The general case for any number of columns could be:

```
import os,itertools

dl=os.listdir(".")

ncols = 3

for t in itertools.zip_longest(*(dl[i::ncols] for i in range(ncols)),fillvalue=""):
    print(("{:<20}"*ncols).format(*t))
```

(generating `ncols` shifted lists, interleaving them, and generating the format accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible with `os.listdir()`. You may have to conside other options like [How to print a list more nicely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524126/how-to-print-a-list-more-nicely).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using function `pairwise` from this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/7588582)

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    return izip(a, a)

for f1, f2 in pairwise(os.listdir(os.curdir)):
    print f1 + '\t' + f2
```

Comment: problem is if number of elements is odd it misses the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for i,k in zip(os.listdir(os.curdir)[0::2], os.listdir(os.curdir)[1::2]): print i,k
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print the output of `os.listdir()` in columns taking care of  computing the number of columns by splitting the terminal's width given by the environment variable `COLUMNS`.

The result is similar to the customary output of `ls` and it works on iPython and Jupyter Notebooks.

```
import os
import shutil

def list_files(directory):
    files = sorted(os.listdir(directory))
    max_filename_length = max(len(file) for file in files)  # Get the maximum length of filenames

    terminal_width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns # int(os.getenv('COLUMNS', 80)) 
    min_column_width = max_filename_length + 2  # minimum width for each column

    columns = max(1, terminal_width // min_column_width)  # adjust the number of columns based on terminal width
    rows = -(-len(files) // columns)  # ceiling division to get # of rows (same as ceil(len(files) / columns))

    for i in range(rows):
        row = ''
        for j in range(columns):
            index = j * rows + i
            if index < len(files):
                filename = files[index]
                row += filename.ljust(max_filename_length + 2)  # adjust spaces for alignment
        print(row)

!rm -rf test;mkdir test; for i in {1..100..10};do touch test/file$i;done;touch test/file22looooongfile

# Usage
#list_files(dir_name)
list_files('test')
# Output:
# file1               file21              file31              file51               file71              file91              
# file11              file22looooongfile  file41              file61               file81
```

Compared to the output of `ls` in IPython:

```
!ls test
# file1         file21              file31          file51          file71          file91
# file11        file22looooongfile  file41          file61          file81
```

The `ls` command in Jupyter Notebooks seems to pack the columns better by adapting each columns's width to the width of its largest element.