# formatting print statement based on different end argument values

Tags: python

I am making a UI for termux terminal on android.

This code below prints the content of the directory.

It works perfectly fine but the output is not even, ie, irregular spaces between the columns.

I've seen people using format but in my case the end argument value differ on each print.

[image: output]

```
def display_dir(dir_name):
    direc = os.listdir(dir_name)
    for index, d in enumerate(direc):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        print(f"{index}- {d}", end=" " * 10)
    else:
        print(f"{index}- {d}", end="\n")
```

but I want perfectly aligned 2 column output.I've tried many things. Is there a short way to do this?

I actually have a solution where I check the longest string and add white spaces for remaining strings but it's not optimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a list more nicely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524126/how-to-print-a-list-more-nicely)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create nice column output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989334/create-nice-column-output-in-python)

Comment: @Tomerikoo it deleted some elements from the list and I need indexing too which I couldn't find.

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo the post you suggested is for nested lists. Mine is a single list. But I might try slicing it....thanks btw.

Comment: Sure, it's just to get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```py
def display_dir(dir_name):
    direc = os.listdir(dir_name)
    max_len = len(max(direc, key=len))

    for index, d in enumerate(direc):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            print("{:2}- {:<{}}".format(index, d, max_len), end=" ")
        else:
            print("{:2}- {:<{}}".format(index, d, max_len), end="\n")
```

Or even further:

```py
def display_dir(dir_name):
    direc = os.listdir(dir_name)
    
    max_len_even = len(max(direc[::2], key=len))
    max_len_odd = len(max(direc[1::2], key=len))
    index_pad_len = len(str(len(direc)))

    for index, d in enumerate(direc):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            print("{:{}}- {:<{}}".format(index, index_pad_len, d, max_len_even), end=" ")
        else:
            print("{:{}}- {:<{}}".format(index, index_pad_len, d, max_len_odd), end="\n")
```

Comment: I've tried both but both of the showing the same error: `ValueError: Format specifier missing precision`.......I haven't used Python since long time....Am I using correct Python version?

Comment: My bad! I have edited my answer, use that instead.

Comment: `max_len` was actually the longest directory `type -> str` instead of the length of it `type -> int`.